# SQL dynamic column names based on event order

Tags: sql, pivot, common-table-expression, dynamic-sql

I need to dynamically create columns that are named based of the run occurrence.  If I have data as such:

```
RunID   TestID   Status
-----   ------   ------
1       200      Passed
2       200      Failed
3       300      Failed
4       400      Not Complete
5       400      Passed
6       400      Passed
```

What I need to return is:

```
TestID    Run1          Run2    Run3
------    ----          ----    ----
200       Passed        Failed
300       Failed
400       Not Complete  Passed  Passed
```

I first can call all the runs but pivoting on the status to align itself in the dynamic run is where I get lost.  Do I have to use a CTE to get the runs, then one to get the max count a TestId has been called and then build column string names based on 1 to max(count(TestID))?  How do I then get that into columns that hold the correct status.  Is a pivot even where I need to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If SQL Server.

You can use the window function ROW_NUMBER() to get the distinct Run Numbers, and then we simply run a dynamic pivot for the final results

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) 
Select  @SQL = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName('Run'+cast(RN as varchar(25))) From (Select Distinct RN=Row_Number() over (Partition By TestID Order By RunID) from YourTable) A Order By 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'')   
Select  @SQL = 'Select TestID,' + @SQL + ' 
                From (
                        Select TestID,Item=''Run''+cast(Row_Number() over (Partition By TestID Order By RunID) as varchar(25)),Value=Status 
                         From  YourTable
                     ) A
                Pivot (max(Value) For Item in (' + @SQL + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Returns

```
TestID  Run1            Run2      Run3
200     Passed          Failed    NULL
300     Failed          NULL      NULL
400     Not Complete    Passed    Passed
```

> **Edit**

```
Select  Stuff( (Select ',' + QuoteName('Run'+cast(RN as varchar(25))) 
   From ( Select Distinct Top 100 Percent RN=Row_Number() over (Partition By RN_TEST_ID Order By RN_RUN_ID) 
           From  td.RUN 
           Where RN_CYCLE_ID = 501
           Order By 1
        ) A
   For XML Path('')),1,1,'') code
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you, I was not even looking at a XML PATH solution to build the column names.  I guess I will need to look into this a bit more.  Thank you John Cappelletti you saved my sanity.

Comment: @S.G. Happy to help.  Looking into XML Path and the window functions is well worth the effort.  Cheers :)

Comment: Any chance you know the best way to keep the columns for "Run<xx>" in order?  To prevent the "Run1" "Run10" from happening?  Also keeping "NULL" values with the actual run and not being pushed to the end?

Comment: @S.G. Just add the Order by in the 1st select  ...) A Order by 1 For XML Path(...

Comment: @S.G. Updated answer just in case my comment was not clear

Comment: I cant get the XML output to be in order with that.  I thought my "where" addition was breaking it but still no dice:
`code`
Stuff(
      (Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName('Run'+cast(RN as varchar(25))) From (
       Select Distinct RN=Row_Number() over (Partition By RN_TEST_ID Order By RN_RUN_ID) 
          from td.RUN where RN_CYCLE_ID = 501) A Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 
`code`

Comment: @S.G. back at my desk.  Give me a moment

Comment: @S.G. If you post a better/more robust sample of data I can help you drag this over the finish line.... Also, you may have to add the WHERE to you sub-query in the Pivot

Comment: Your the man!  That first "DISTINCT" was breaking it, I never would have guessed that.  I was trying to give the row an alias and then use a order by cast(substring(runName,4,3) as INT) to try and sort based on the isolated RN but was getting no where.  Thanks a million.  Now I just have to figure out why a null run gets pushed to the end (If Run 3 didnt do a Test ID, run 4 for that test ID falls in run 3's column)  I'll find it!  Eventually :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135983/discussion-between-s-g-and-john-cappelletti).